# Build all polynomial functions over field $\mathbb{Z}_{k}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Consider two functions $[x^{2}y, x+1]$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{k}$, where $k$ is a prime number.

Is it true that we could build all polynomial functions $P(x)$ over this field using composition of these functions? We should find all $a_{k-2}x^{k-2} + \dots+a_{1}x^{1} + a_{0}$, where $a_{i} \in \mathbb{Z}_{k}$. And composition means: we can build the identity function $x$, and if we have built $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, we can also build $f^2(x)g(x)$, $f(x) + 1$.

**EDIT** : $x^{k-1+l} \equiv x^{l}$. So we just need to build $x^{m}$, where $ 0 \le m < k - 1$.

*My attempt* :

Obviously we can build all $x^{2m+1}$ and even $x^{2m+1} + l \cdot x^{2m}$, where $0 \le l < k$. But I got stuck on how can I get all monomials with even degree. If I built them it's easy to struct all constants , or if I build all constant it will be easy to struct all even-degree monomials (because of Fermat's theorem). But I don't know what to do in this way?

*EDIT* : we could use Fermat's theorem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "build P(X)" using "composition of these functions"? If $f(x)$ is a polynomial that I've got, then can I substitute $y=f(x)$ to get $x^2f(x)$? What about $f(x)+1$, by substituting $f(x)$ for $x$?

Comment: Also what does it mean to compose a function of two variables with a function of one variable?

Comment: @Aravind I mean we could compose two different composition of functions.

Comment: The definition is now clear, thanks.

Comment: @Aravind my bad , sorry!

Comment: Given $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, you are allowed to construct $f(x)+1$ and $f(x)^2g(x)$.  But what elements of $\mathbb{Z}_k[x]$ do you get to start with?  Just $x+1$?  If so, you certainly can't construct any constant polynomials...

Comment: At start we just have $x$, after we could build $x + l$, $l \in \mathbb{Z}_{k}$, after could build $x^{2} \cdot x = x^3$ and so on.

Comment: Then it follows by induction that the leading coefficient must be 1, and the leading monomial must be of odd degree.

Comment: Do you want to construct all formal polynomials, or all polynomial _functions_ $\mathbb{Z}_k\to\mathbb{Z}_k$?  (These are not the same thing; for instance, $x^k$ and $x$ are the same function but different polynomials.  Also, if you mean functions, it's kind of silly to talk about building all polynomials, since _every_ function $\mathbb{Z}_k\to\mathbb{Z}_k$ is given by a polynomial.)

Comment: @EricWofsey sorry , my bad . Of course I want to construct all all functions, all functions , which realizes over $\mathbb{Z}_{k}$.

Comment: @Aravind we know that $x^{k-1} \equiv 1$, so $x^{k+2} \equiv x^{3}$

Comment: @openspace -- Have you tested it for the primes $p=2$ and $p=3$? If not, given that you got stuck, solving those cases (if they work), might show the way forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true.  Let us first assume $k$ is odd.  Note that if we can build a function $f(x)$, then for any $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}_k$ we can also build the function $$g(x)=(x-a)^{k-1}(f(x)-b)+b.$$ Indeed, to build this function we first add $1$ (the residue of) $-b$ times to get $f(x)-b$.  Then since we can build $x-a$, we can multiply by $(x-a)^2$ $(k-1)/2$ times (here we use that $k$ is odd).  Finally, we can add $1$ $b$ times to get $g(x)$.

Now note that if $x\neq a$, $(x-a)^{k-1}=1$ so $g(x)=f(x)$.  On the other hand, $g(a)=b$.  So this means that we can freely modify the value of $f(x)$ at one point at a time.  Repeatedly using this as $a$ ranges over all elements of $\mathbb{Z}_k$ allows us to construct any function at all.

This proves the result when $k$ is odd.  When $k=2$, the only functions we need to build are $0$, $1$, $x$, and $x+1$.  We can obviously build $x$ and $x+1$, and we can build $0$ as $x^2(x+1)$ and thus we can also build $1$.  So the result is true for all primes $k$.

Comment: But how can we get $(x-a)^{k-1}$? Assume we build some $f(x)$. Then we could build $(x-a)^{2}(f(x)-a)$, not $(x-a)^{2}$. Maybe I misunderstand something?

Comment: We can build $(x-a)^2(f(x)-b)$, and so we can build $(x-a)^4(f(x)-b)$, and so we can build $(x-a)^6(f(x)-b)$, and so on.

Comment: My bad. Yes. We could $(x-a)^{2} \cdot q(x)$. Sorry!